# given a number p , find two elements in array whose product = P

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for solution for :

```
Given a array and a number P , find two numbers in array whose product equals P.
```

Looking for solution better than O(n*2) . I am okay with using extra space or other datastructure .Any help is appreciated ?

Comment: this really sounds like homework.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the types of numbers (such as just integers, just positive integers, etc.)?

Comment: no restrictions on the number.

Comment: if there are no restrictions on the numbers (aside from presumably real) the likelihood that there exists a solution approaches zero, especially if one or more of the numbers is a floating point approximation. Classic paper: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try a sliding window approach. First sort all the numbers increasingly, and then use two integers `begin` and `end` to index the current pair of numbers. Initialize `begin` to 0 and `end` to the last position. Then compare the product of `v[begin]` and `v[end]` with `P`:

- If it is equal, you found the answer.
- If it is lower, you must find a bigger product, move `begin` forward.
- If it is higher, you must find a smaller product, move `end` backward.

Here is a C++ code with this idea implemented. This solution is O(n*log(n)) because of the sorting, if you can assume the data is sorted then you can skip the sorting for an O(n) solution.

```
pair<int, int> GetProductPair(vector<int>& v, int P) {
  sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  int begin = 0, end = static_cast<int>(v.size()) - 1;
  while (begin < end) {
    const int prod = v[begin] * v[end];
    if (prod == P) return make_pair(begin, end);
    if (prod < P) ++begin;
    else --end;
  }
  return make_pair(-1, -1);
}
```

Comment: I have the intuition that this might not find the solution.

Comment: @pascal: This technique works, and it can be proven. However, doing this after sorting is not useful in terms of complexity. You can simply scan the items and use binary search to find the complementing operand. The overall complexity is still O(N Log N). 
The advantage of this technique is when the array is already sorted, so you can achieve linear time.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking about moving `begin` once too far, and having to move it back in order to try a pair with a larger `end`. But in this mental image, I neglect that the array was also sorted on the `end` side...

Comment: This might not work for array which has negative numbers?  Ex: v = [-8,-2,2,8] and p = 16. first v[begin]*v[end] = -8*8 = -64 which is less than 16 so we proceed with the increasing begin. So in this way we will miss the pair (-8,-2).

Comment: @anilkumar: Yes.  If P is positive and there are any negative numbers, you need to solve 2 subproblems after sorting.  Let k be the first index containing a positive number.  You need to solve the subproblem [1..k-1] vs [1..k-1], which can be done by (conceptually) reversing this range and "forgetting" their negative signs, and also solve the subproblem [k..n] vs [k..n] (in the usual way).  If P is negative, then a variation of the original algorithm works: start `begin` at k-1, and move it *backwards* when the current product > P.  Either way, it's O(n) time, excluding sort time.

Answer (score 26):

Make a pass through the array, and add the elements to a Hashtable.  For each element x added, check whether P/x already exists in the Hashtable - if it does then x and P/x is one of your solutions.  This'd be about as optimal as you'll get.

Comment: @Michael - does that matter?  Granted P/x might not be exactly spot-on an element in the Hashtable - if this poses a problem then sorting the array and binary searching to locate the closest element to P/x and multiplying that element by x to check for P might be a better choice.

Comment: your answer is, of course, spot on. However, some level of quantization / binning must be done in the implementation for this to work. Then again, such quantization is also necessary for the O(n^2) algorithm. Please forgive comments posted late in the evening. :)

Answer (score 3):

This one would work only for integers:
Decompose P as product of prime numbers. By dividing these in two groups you can obtain the pairs that gives P as product. Now you just have to check both of them are present in the array, this is where a hash table would be very useful. Also, while creating the hash table, you could also filter the array of repeating values, values that are greater than P, or even values that have prime factors not contained in P.

Comment: Good idea, although decomposing might be a little bit more than O(n²).

Comment: @liori: Not necessarily, if you have a precomputed list of prime numbers, then it's O(n).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Although to store primes necessary to factorize any 64-bit integer you'd need ~0.8GB of memory. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a hash that will be populated in the steps below.
- Iterate over the elements of the array one by one. Say current element is n

  - If the number P is exactly divisible by n

    - check if n is one of the values of the hash. If yes then that key, value are the two numbers that we are looking for and we can break.
    - if n is not in the values of the hash then add n,x in a hash where n*x = P
  - If the number P is not exactly divisible by n then continue with next element of array
- If we reach end of the array then there are no such two numbers in the array whose product is P

This algo is of O(n)

Answer (score 0):

1.sort the numbers into an array A, removing any zeroes, in O(nlogn) time

2.create an array B such that B[i] = P/A[I] in O(n) time

3.for every B[k] in B, do a binary search in A for that element, takes O(nlogn) time in the worst case

if the element B[k] exists in the array A at position m, then A[k] * A[m] = P
otherwise no such pair exists

the total running time is O(nlogn)

Of course this may run into difficulties on a real machine due to floating point error

Answer (score 0):

*Updated to provide the implementation.*

O(n+P) solution, ignoring the case of P equal to 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    auto arr = new vector<int>();
    int P, numOfEle, ele;

    cout << "The number of elements to be entered: " << endl;
    cin >> numOfEle;
    cout << "Please enter the elements: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfEle; i++){
        cin >> ele;
        arr->push_back(ele);
    }
    cout << "Please enter P: " << endl;
    cin >> P;


    //O(n+P) solution, ignoring the case of P equal to 0
    bool* factorsInNeed = new bool[P];
    for (int i = 0; i < P; i++)
        factorsInNeed[i] = false;
    for (auto i : *arr){
        if (i != 0 && P/(double)i == P/i){ //if divisble
            if (factorsInNeed[i]){
                cout << "A solution: " << i << " & " << P/i << endl;
                break;
            }
            factorsInNeed[P/i] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean factors_Of_Product_In_Array(int a[],int product,int factorsLimit)
{
    int i = 0,count = 0;
    boolean flag = false;

    if(factorsLimit==0)
        flag = false;

    //If product value is zero - only verify if there is any '0' value in array
    else if(product==0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==0)
                flag = true;
        }
    }

    //If product value is 1 - Verify at least factorsLimit number of 1's should be present in array
    else if(product==1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==0)
                count=count+1;
        }

        if(count==factorsLimit)//Verifying if the number of 1's is equal to number of factors required
            flag = true;
    }

    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<a.length && count!=factorsLimit ;i++)
        {
            if(product%a[i]==0)
            {
                product = product/a[i];
                count = count+1;
                System.out.println(" "+a[i]+" ");
            }
        }

    if(count==factorsLimit)
        flag = true;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my shot, it only compares any factors with each other once

```
P <- The Number
theArray <- new array[theData]
factors <- new array[]
isFactor <- new map(init: false)
factorCount <- 0
i <- 0
while i is in theArray
    num <- theArray[i]
    if (isFactor[num])
        skip
    if num modulo P == 0
        isFactor[num] <- true
        j <- 0
        while j is in factors
            if factors[j] * num == P
                return (num, factors[j])
            j++
        factors.push(num)
        factorCount++
    i++
```

Comment: Does `factors` ever have anything placed into it?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is the best solution but it works. you can try and optimize it.

```
public class CombInput
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Value;
    }

  public List<string> GetCombinations(List<string> values)
        {

            List<CombInput> input = new List<CombInput>();
           List<string> outputvalues = new List<string>();
            int counter = 1;
             foreach (String c in values)
             {
                 input.Add(new CombInput { ID = counter, Value = c });

                 counter++;
             }
            var Output = from i in input
                        select i;

            string Final = Output.Select(query => query.Value).Aggregate((a, b) => a + "|" + b);

            while (!Output.ToList().Exists(s=>s.Value.ToString()==Final))
            {
                var store = Output;  
                var  Output1= 
                (from o in Output
                          from v in input
                         where (v.ID < o.ID && !(store.Any(a=>a.Value==v.Value + "|" + o.Value)))
                               select new CombInput { ID = v.ID, Value = v.Value + "|" + o.Value });

                var Outputx = (from s in store select s)
                .Concat
                (from s in Output1.ToList() select s);
                Output = Outputx;
            }


            foreach (var v in Output)
                outputvalues.Add(v.Value);
            return outputvalues.ToList();
        }

 public List<string> GetProductCombinations(List<int> nums, int productCriteria)
        {
            List<string> input = (from i in nums
                                 select i.ToString()).ToList();
            input = GetCombinations(input);

            var O = from i in input
                    where i.Split('|').ToList().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList().Aggregate((a, b) => a * b) == productCriteria
                    select i;


            List<string> output=new List<string>();
            foreach (string o in O)
            {
                output.Add(o);
            }
            return output;
        }


 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             List<string> output = new List<string>();
            List<int> nums = new List<int>();
            int[] numsarr ={1,2,3,4,6,7,8,12};
            nums = numsarr.ToList();
            output = GetProductCombinations(nums, 12);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

void PrintPairOfProduct(int arr[],int size,int k)
             {

```
          int i,temp[MAX];
           memset(temp,1,MAX);
           for(i=0;i<size;++i)
           {
            if(k % arr[i] == 0 && temp[arr[i]] != -1 && temp[k/arr[i]] != -1)
            {
             if((temp[k/arr[i]] * arr[i]) == k)
             {
             printf("Product of %d * %d = %d",k/arr[i],arr[i],k);``

             temp[k/arr[i]] = -1;
             temp[arr[i]] = -1;
            }
            temp[arr[i]] = arr[i];
```

`}}`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int arr[]={2,15,4,5,6,7};
 const int  c = 30;
 int i = 0,j=1;
 int num =0;
 while ( i<= 6 )
 {
    num = arr[i] * arr[j];
    if ( num == 30)
    {
       printf("Pairs[%d,%d]\t",arr[i],arr[j]);
    }
    if (j == 5 )
    {
       i = i+1;
       j = i + 1;
       if (j==6)
       {
          break;
       }
       else
       {
       continue;
       }
    }
    j= j+1;

 }


 return 0;
}
```