# Excel VBA: identify all possible combinations

Tags: excel, combinations, vba

I have two accounting records that i try to match. 
Accounting record 1 contains the following (eg.) data:

```
A=100,
B=150 and
C=210.
```

Accounting record 2 contains the following (eg.) data:

```
x1=55,
x2=45,
x3=90,
x4=60,
x5=80,
x6=70,
x7=20 and
x8=40.
```

Mention should be made that data in both accounting records can be both negative and positive.

All the 3 transactions presented within Accounting record 1 is the sum of at least 1 transactions within accounting record 2. No doubling the transactions is to be considered.

Specifically, I need an excel vba code to get me the following results:

```
A=x1+x2;
B=x3+x4; and 
C=x5+x6+x7+x8.
```

Since B can also be equal to x3+x7+x8, I need the code to loop through the possible solutions until all transactions within Accounting record 2 are allocated.

Any tips or recommended steps to take?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is 8 items representative of the size of the data set? You could brute-force it by looking at every possible subset of record 2, but because this is O(n!) you couldn't do the same if it's more than a couple of items larger.

Comment: I don't know if someone will write up a comprehensive solution for this with no prior effort from you, as it does require a bit of legwork. But [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757393/given-a-number-p-find-two-elements-in-array-whose-product-p) is some inspiration to start you off. Those solutions would have to be altered to find all solutions instead of any single solution.

Comment: @jsheeran: the number of data sites is much higher.

Comment: @Vegard: of course i would not have expected someone to do the work. That is why I have asked for tips and steps. In this way I could focus on the approach before doing the modelling itself. Thanks for the link as well. I will look into it and revert with a proposed solution :)